# Add css & javascript file to All Pages of NetSuite

Tags: css, netsuite, suitescript

I need to add a css file or javascript to each of the NetSuite pages to make the page direction RTL.
I tried adding it through :

SuiteScript >> Client >> Deployment : All Records,

And already succeeded in adding them to some pages. But I need to add the code to all pages of the NetSuite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetSuite does not provide an option to add CSS/JS to every page. Only certain pages are scriptable as you have discovered.

You could use something like [Tamerpermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to achieve this. However that would require installation on each end user's machine.